# How to correct a jQuery syntax error?

Tags: jquery, syntax, toggle, shopping-cart

I'm trying to update a Total: (`span.wrap p span`) field at the bottom of a form using jQuery.

I have a few checkboxes, each of which has an associated price contained within the `title` attribute like so: `title="$2"`.

I'd the Total: field to update dynamically when the user clicks a checkbox. Here is the script I have, but it's throwing a syntax error as shown.

```
$("input:checkbox").toggle(
        var v = $(this).attr("title").substr(-1) * 1; // syntax error here. subtstr() eliminates the $ sign
        var t = $("span.wrap p span").text() * 1; // converts the string to a number
        function () {
            $("span.wrap p span").text(t + v);
        },
        function () {
            $("span.wrap p span").text(t - v);
        }
    );
```

Note: The total field has an initial value of `0`. There are four checkboxes; perhaps I need to use `each()`?

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: in the first place why don't you just put '2' in title instead of '$2'?

Comment: it's a title field. perhaps he wants it to show up neatly on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle accepts a function

```
$("input:checkbox").toggle(function() {
   var v...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a toggle function, afaik you can only define code within the two function blocks.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
var v = $(this).attr("title").substr(-1) * 1
```

to

```
var v = $(this).attr("title").substr(1) * 1
```

Comment: also wrap it into a function block as suggested by d.